# Using jar file in .net platform

Tags: .net, jar, hsm

I have hsm device and Java library file(jar) for accessing this device. it is only reached and signed with jar file. But i have to write code in .net platform. How to use this jar file accessing and signing to hsm in .net platform?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running your .NET application on a Windows system. Your HSM should have come with a CSP and/or KSP for Windows. Install that on your Windows system and then reference the certificate programmatically via an X509Certificate2 object, just like you normally would. Similarly, tools like signtool should also work once the KSP is installed by referencing the certificate by its thumbprint. To see the certificate's thumbprint, open certmgr.msc, expand your Personal store, and look at the Certificates available.